# Proof of Left adjoint preserves Left Kan extension

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

My intuitive understanding is the following:

Kan extensions are the closest "approximation" of a given functor, that factors along a given functor. What's happening is that left adjoints preserve colimits, so this guarantees the existence of the Kan extension of the composition. So since $\mathcal{L}$ is the 'closest' functor to $\mathcal{L}$, we should have,
$$\text{Lan}_\mathcal{F} (\mathcal{L}\circ \mathcal{G})\cong\mathcal{L}\circ \text{Lan}_\mathcal{F} \mathcal{G}.$$
So I was expecting this.

[image]

Now for the proof, the idea I felt was to apply Yoneda in some way. So,
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}^{\mathcal{B}}}(\mathcal{L}\text{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathcal{G},\mathcal{K}) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{B}}}(\text{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathcal{G},\mathcal{R}\mathcal{K})\cong\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{A}}}(\mathcal{G},\mathcal{R}\mathcal{K}\circ \mathcal{F})\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}^{\mathcal{A}}}(\mathcal{L}\mathcal{G},\mathcal{K}\mathcal{F})$$
Doesn't this already say, by precomp-left Kan adjointness, that $\text{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}(\mathcal{L}\circ \mathcal{G})\cong \mathcal{L}\circ \text{Lan}_\mathcal{F} \mathcal{G}$? In the usual books they assume $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{L}\text{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathcal{G}$, and make some arguments I don't understand.

Comment: It would be good to explain what the arguments are, that you don’t understand. It also should go without saying that your post should be kept reasonably polite and coherent.

Comment: Why do I need to assume $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{L} \text{Lan}_{\mathcal{F}}\mathcal{G}$? What else needs to be done?

Comment: A) you should add any further context or questions in the main post. B) While I am about to start learning more advanced category theory such as Kan extensions, I haven’t yet. So, I cannot help.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that left adjoints preserve left Kan extensions can be motivated in many ways according to the generality you are forced to work in.

Your argument is a viable solution provided there exists a "left Kan extension along $F$" functor, which by uniqueness of adjoints must be a left adjoint to precomposition with $F$. This is not always the case; it is the case when the left extensions you are considering are pointwise, and strictly speaking this is a less general concept than the bare definition of Kan extension with its 2-dimensional universal property.

Left adjoint 1-cells of any 2-category, however, preserve left Kan extensions, and this can be deduced quite swiftly from some basic 2-category theory. If you feel you might need this more general argument, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 

I am a physicist, my goal is sheaf theory/microlocal sheaves. I also believe I would need Grothendieck topolgy/sheafification there. I only want to read what's necessary. But I hate Kashiwara-Schapira style and notation. Much of the stuff you mentioned flew over my head, what is the ideal trajectory for me?

Comment: In particular I don't know what pointwise vs general Kan extension means. But I guess, in my case, the target category will be complete/cocomplete, and initial categories will at least be locally small?

Comment: @MrPajeet pointwise Kan extensions are the ones whose values are given by (co)limits. You should perhaps ask a separate question for references, in which you explain your goals.

Comment: @MrPajeet it would indeed be quite helpful if you explained what are your goal and your background!

Comment: @fosco Your book is amazing and funny. Actually I prefered the shorter 42 pages notes. fundamental kata of coend-fu made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal A, \mathcal C, \mathcal D, \mathcal E$ be categories, $L:\mathcal D \to \mathcal E$ be a left adjoint to $R:\mathcal E\to \mathcal D$, $F:\mathcal C$ and $K:\mathcal C\to \mathcal A$ such that the left Kan extension $\mathtt{Lan}_K F$ exists.

[image: Diagram of the situation]

Recall that the adjunction $L\dashv R$ induces a natural isomorphism $\mathcal E^\mathcal A(L-, =)\simeq \mathcal D^\mathcal A(-, R=)$, and that the left Kan extension along $K$ can be defined as a left adjoint to $-\circ K$.

Let $G$ be any functor $\mathcal A\to \mathcal E$. Then we have the following chain of isomorphisms:

$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal E^\mathcal A(L(\mathtt{Lan}_K F), G) & \simeq \mathcal D^\mathcal A(\mathtt{Lan}_K F, RG) \\
& \simeq \mathcal D^\mathcal C(F, RGK) \\
& \simeq \mathcal E^\mathcal C(LF, GK) \\
& \simeq \mathcal E^\mathcal A(\mathtt{Lan}_K (LF), G)
\end{aligned}$

Hence, by the Yoneda Lemma, we have $L(\mathtt{Lan}_K F)\simeq \mathtt{Lan}_K (LF)$.

Comment: In the last step you are assuming $\text{Lan}_K LF$ exists no? If it exists, yes it will be unique up to isomorphism is fine by Yoneda as I have stated in the question, but I feel something fishy is happening, mainly existence stuff. Maybe I am just confused

Comment: I mean to say is Kan-precomp adjointness applicable?